# Exclude URL parameters from analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm in the admin section of Google Analytics: view/view settings/ Exclude URL Query Parameters optional

I'd like to ignore url parameters in my analytics so that:
example.com/somepage?cid=123456&utm_medium=Display&utm_campaign=somecampaign&utm_source=GDN

is the same as:
example.com/somepage

Within the Google Analytics interface above I excluded these parameters: utm_source, utm_medium, utm_term, utm_campaign, cid

But, cid is still coming through?

Does anyone know why? The others have been removed (the utm ones)

Comment: So the only parameter you're excluding is cid, correct? Do you have any filters setup for the profile?

Answer (score 0):

The Exclude Query Parameters "feature" in Google Analytics is case sensitive.  Does the parameter show up as CID on the website?